# Rhetorical device? Answer question with example of the answer showing how to find the answer

Tags: questions, rhetorical-devices

Imagine the following online dialog.

Question: What is a hyperlink?

Answer: Click on the following, [`https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hyperlink`](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hyperlink)<s>, or type it into your web browser</s>.

(Thanks to @RegDwigнt♦ for [suggesting](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/464362/rhetorical-device-answer-question-with-example-of-the-answer-showing-how-to-fin#comment1123896_464362) I use a definition from somewhere other than [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20hyperlink).)

The answer provides an example of a *hyperlink* that shows the answer to the question of what a *hyperlink* is.

Is there a specific name for this rhetorical device, where one is shown how to find an answer through an example of the answer?

---

**My Thoughts**

My first thought for the right word was [meta](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meta#Adjective). From [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meta#Adjective) ...

> meta
>
> (informal) Self-referential; structured analogously, but at a higher level.
>
> Suppose you have a genie that grants you three wishes. If you wish for infinite wishes, that is a meta wish.

... but I wonder if there is a more specific rhetorical device that would describe the situation.

Thanks. I'm excited to be part of this site.

---

**Edit:** I was originally motivated to ask this question because of a [programming example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-a-file-but-show-several-surrounding-lines#comment54766756_9081) on [another forum](https://stackoverflow.com). @RobbieGoodwin suggested that the question be limited to English language, so I am including a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/555Jj.png) to a screenshot of that programming example and my explanation. The question is *not* about programming, it's about a strategy used for answering a question. (As a new user, I appreciate the suggestion.)

Comment: https://academic.oup.com/hcr/article-abstract/2/2/172/4637468?redirectedFrom=PDF

Comment: That's a perfect description of what I'm discussing, @Jim. Would the answer be simply "an indirect question", or is it deeper than that?

Comment: Well, it would be an *indirect **answer***...

Comment: Oops. Good point. By the way, I liked your __indirect answer__. The cleverness was duly noted.

Comment: So what's wrong with *self-referential*?

Comment: @linguistictum , I think _self-referential_ could work as well. I'm not sure it's as specific as I'd like to be, though.

Comment: A 'meta-definition'?  (Are they always enthymematic?)

Comment: @Ami, I must admit some ignorance on this part. I looked up _enthymematic_. Yes, I believe that there will be an unstated premise, but I'm not sure I understand your question. I _can_ say, without being unsure, that it does not always have to be a definition. It can definitely be a situation where one is asking how to use something, be it intellectually, physically, computationally, academically, etc.)

Comment: I _love_ these comments. Some of them could easily be answers. I will be spending more time in the "ELU" Stack Exchange community in the future.

Comment: I see your point -- the answer would be a 'meta-explanation'.

Comment: @AmI, I think that 'meta-explanation' is one of the two best answers, along with the 'indirect answer' from Jim. If either of you want to post as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: @Jim, I think that 'indirect answer' is one of the two best answers, along with the 'meta-explanation' from Jim. If either of you want to post as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm new to ELU, so I'd like to know how to improve things.

Comment: Whatever you're really asking, would you not get more help from a forum devoted to whatever language you're programming in, or at worst one designed for programmers in general?

This has nothing useful to do with English, even if it could be translated to English… which you clearly proved while going to the trouble of posting all that programming stuff, then attempting to explain it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @RobbieGoodwin . I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Be wary that Google shows a completely different result page to every single person using it. So your example does not work for me at all. I have no idea what you're seeing. Knowing Google I can believe it's clever or funny, but that's not what they're showing to me. (Like, it's still perfectly clear what you're after, from your description alone, even with the example broken. I'm just giving you a headsup that it *is* broken, because on a different occasion it might actually bite you in the butt if you don't realize these things.)

Comment: Are not rhetorical devices a feature of English, rather than programming? Computer languages, and explanations thereof, are often based on and use English, respectively. Though I still do not know how appropriate my question is to this forum, the preceding verbiage elucidates my reason for posting the answer here. P.S. If I asked programmers to name a rhetorical device for a situation, I think they would rightly say that the question was far from [_apropos of_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apropos%20of) programming.

Comment: That is a good point, @RegDwigнt . I will use a different hyperlink.

Comment: Also,  @RegDwigнt♦, завтра, играем на ложках. Haha.

Comment: Yeah I believe the example is fine, you just need a screenshot alongside the link in such cases, rather than disposing of the example wholesale and trying to think of a different one entirely. I know that many people around these parts are up in arms about screenshots, but there's a time and place for everything. It's not what you use, it's how you use it, is my stance. Also, I can't actually play them spoons (though I do own a whole bunch). I only play the bayan. So that's a big stinking lie right there, though I do admit to just that in the video description.

Comment: Thanks @RegDwigнt♦. I made the change because of the comment by RobbieGoodwin - I had the complete example from StackOverflow. You can see what was there by looking in the edit history. Thanks for your help. And thanks for the video. My Russian-born wife loved it!

Comment: Here's how the first part of my question looked before: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6zXQ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6zXQ.png). I'm just trying to learn the ins and outs of EL&U, so I'm open to suggestions and help. (I hope I will still be open to suggestions and help after I'll have used the site for many years...) Thanks.

Comment: The answer is self-referential (a mix of regular and meta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two answers given as comments which I consider the best. Since the users haven't posted what they wrote as answers, I will note them here and credit the users.

**Answer 1: "Indirect Answer"**

@Jim [gave](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/464362/rhetorical-device-answer-question-with-example-of-the-answer-showing-how-to-fin#comment1120626_464362) a sort-of example of the situation I was describing by posting the following link. Note that I say, "sort-of answer," because the link itself isn't indirect, i.e. the link itself isn't an instance of an *indirect answer*.

[https://academic.oup.com/hcr/article-abstract/2/2/172/4637468](https://academic.oup.com/hcr/article-abstract/2/2/172/4637468?redirectedFrom=PDF)

There, one may read,

> The mechanisms through which an indirect response to a question counts as a direct answer to that question can fruitfully be regarded as a process in which the listener supplies, constructs, infers, or is reminded of such statements as will (together with the indirect response itself) allow the inference of a plausible direct answer.

The abstract to which the link refers adds an idea that is crucial to the situation I described, specifically,

> [P]articipants [in a conversation] expect each other to cooperate in making utterances “make sense.”

@Jim really understood the question, because he *answered indirectly* that my situation was an *indirect answer*. Clever.

**Answer 2: "Meta-Explanation"**

@AmI [gave](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/464362/rhetorical-device-answer-question-with-example-of-the-answer-showing-how-to-fin#comment1120894_464362) the great answer above, i.e. that the appropriate rhetorical device is a *meta-explanation*. In addition, @AmI used the appropriate and fancy term, *enthymematic*, which is interesting as regards this question. Here's the 
[definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/enthymematic), which actually redirects to *enthymeme*:

> noun Logic. 
>   a syllogism or other argument in which a premise or the conclusion is unexpressed.

While I think *meta-explanation* would be a more-specific name than *indirect answer* for a rhetorical device such as I explained, I couldn't find any web examples of the former, while I could find them for the latter.

I'm interested to hear what you users of EL&U think. Do you find one of these answers more appropriate for the situation described?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of the principle of **[Show, Don't Tell](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShowDontTell)**:
*using demonstrative techniques, rather than blatant or thinly-veiled narration, to establish narrative elements*.

The definition above comes from creative writing, but we use it at lot in scientific and technical teaching, too.